# php how to get all name of files in directory from url

Tags: php

hello how to get all name of files in directory from url http:// like this
[directory listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlsb1.jpg)

From Url Http:// external link Not from internal folder
and Thank you

Comment: In more than 95% of the cases, the directory listing is prohibited / not allowed on the servers. Still you can use `readdir()` or `scandir()`

Comment: Not work in external url http:// :(

Answer (score 0):

Which directory you need, you have to create a file with name .htaccess and write inside;

```
Options +Indexes
```

Comment: i creat .htaccess and put inside
probelm here
Warning: scandir(http://directoryindex/s/): failed to open dir: not implemented in C:\AppServ\www\me\config.php on line 15

Warning: scandir(): (errno 11): Resource temporarily unavailable in C:\AppServ\www\me\config.php on line 15

Comment: @aaade You don't need extra code. You just create a file with a code which i shared with you. You don't need extra function etc.

Comment: Thank you my friend but you Did not understand me
i want to get name of files in this Url
like this url
http://mbdou-ds47.ru/images/s/
i want get names s.txt s2.txt dz.jpg